# Discrepancy between metafor and weighted lm() standard errors

Tags: r, meta-analysis, lm

My friend and I are trying to understand why a weighted `lm()` v. a fixed-effect  `rma` model from the `metafor` package are producing identical meta-analytic point estimates, but different standard errors (and therefore *p* values and 95% CIs) for those estimates.

For example:

```
#install and call metafor package
install.packages("metafor")
library(metafor)

#read in example data for standardized mean differences and standard errors
d<-c(0.38, 0.36, -0.35, 1.55, 0.26, 1.2, 0.38, 0.46, 0.27, 0.24, -0.07, -0.26, -0.31, 1.15, 0.23, 0.29, 0.38, 0.19, 0.4, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.34)
d.se<-c(1.8, 3.49, 1.53, 4.96, 2.08, 3.48, 0.07, 0.07, 0.09, 0.09, 0.01, 0.09, 6.64, 5.08, 7.44, 0.16, 0.18, 2.05, 0.17, 0.16, 0.17, 0.22, 0.09)
d.v<-d.se*d.se

#run fixed-effects intercept-only models with lm() and metafor
lm.intercept<-lm(d ~ 1, weights=I(1/d.v))
summary(lm.intercept)

metafor.intercept<-rma(yi=d, vi=d.v, method="FE")
summary(metafor.intercept)
```

Both approaches yield the appropriate estimate of -0.0361, but the `lm()` approach yields a standard error of 0.02585 (and therefore the estimate is not significant at the *p* >.05 level), whereas the `metafor` approach yields a standard error of 0.0095 (and therefore the estimate is significant at the *p* < .05 level). The same discrepancy also occurs for moderators that you add to the model (e.g., `d~d.se`).

I am somewhat confident that the `lm()` approach is mistakenly estimating the standard error somehow (I've worked through the calculations for this example by hand: [google doc spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UZgedUS1V2K_KX0S1WYDDwQjmlNwVGGxdcVZDHpF65M/edit#gid=0)), but my friend and I would like to better understand why/how this is occurring.

Does anyone have any idea of what's causing the discrepancy in standard errors between the two models?

Comment: The PDF manual for Stata's  `vwls` command contains the answer to your question: http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rvwls.pdf See Section "Remarks and examples".

Comment: Thanks @boscovich! Having a friend run model in Stata now to confirm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A while ago, I wrote up an extensive comparison between the `rma()` function from the `metafor` package and the `lm()` and `lme()` functions (the latter from the `nlme` package) for fitting fixed- and random/mixed-effects models. You can find this on the metafor package website:

http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:rma_vs_lm_and_lme

To briefly summarize: When you use the `lm()` and `lme()` functions with weights, then this fits models that assume that the weights (i.e., sampling variances) are known only up to a proportionality constant -- which is in fact the error variance that is estimated. Those are not standard meta-analytic models as commonly described in the literature.